# Reference for modular theory on $B(H)$

Tags: reference-request, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-information

I am looking for a reference for (Tomita-Takesaki) modular theory that focuses specifically on the case of type I factors (i.e. $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$).

**Background**: I know plenty of references that treat Tomita-Takesaki theory. However, they all consider general (or at least $\sigma$-finite) von Neumann algebras. From the point of view of structure theory of von Neumann algebras, type I factors are of course not very interesting and one does not need Tomita-Takesaki theory to understand them.

Yet in quantum information theory or mathematical physics the modular group and other modular operations often show up, and more than once I have been asked for a reference. It seems like an overkill to recommend someone to read up on general von Neumann algebra theory when all they are interested in are von Neumann algebras of the form $B(H)$.

Moreover, things are technically much easier in this setting, which would make such a reference also desirable from the didactic viewpoint. In particular, if there is a reference that only treats finite-dimensional algebras, I would still be interested.